# MP4 file links download instead of playing

Tags: media

How can I make MP4 file download the file instead of playing it on wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make updates on your web-server instead of WordPress.
You can set mime type for mp4 files to `application/octet-stream`.

Using .htaccess (Apache):

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
```

For nginx [check documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types)

If you need to change mp4 mime type on upload, you can use this hook:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wpse_320375_remove_mime_types');

function wpse_320375_remove_mime_types($mimes){
   $mimes['mp4'] = 'application/octet-stream';
}
```